# How I do to run only a software in more than one computer?

Tags: linux, cluster, redundancy

I need to run a unique instance of a software in more than one computer, how I do this without a centralizer server?

For example:

4 computers interconnected by the local network, 2 of then has "the hardware" that I need to send a requisition.

I need to create a software that runs through the 4 computers, for if one of these computers with "the hardware" broke, or have any problem, the requisition go for the another computer with "the hardware". Also to balance the requisitions between all computers with "the hardware" and don't get an overhead and long queues.

**Obs:**

A single server to center is not an option because if the server broke all the queues stop together.

I can not create a server with a redundancy as a cluster because the cost is expensive.

I'm using linux

**Edit:**

My software need to receive requisitions of all the computers, for distribute between the computers that have "the hardware" that I named it "SAT".

SAT is a hardware that receive a requisition through your specific ".dll" that is on the computer where the SAT was plugged.

Comment: Something like this would take specialized software.

Comment: @Zoredache I don't have a lot of knowledge about architecture and infrastructure. This is an idea that I have to a new project in my company.

Comment: @Zoredache Can you help-me? You know any software to do this?

Comment: See DHCP and DNS for examples as primary and secondary services.

Comment: There are many potential ways to do this, depending on requirements, skillsets, technologies, etc..  Too broad of a question for Q/A format.

Comment: @jlehtinen Can you answer with only one way to do this? just for me to have a horizon to search.

Comment: Honestly, the question is too broad for me to even make guess at best practice.  How do you query or access "the hardware"? How do you intend to access or transmit this data?  Is it served to clients?  How do they connect?  Is it across internet or just in LAN?  Do you need it stored in a database?  etc. etc. etc.   You need to build out your requirements more fully and come up some basic plans for how it needs to work.  Then answering questions around what to use will be easier.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, more information is needed. Can you be more specific? What is the software you are needing to run as that will define what options are available. Also need clarification on what you mean by the 'hardware' that is required. You need to be able to define if you need redundancy, fail-over, high availability (sounds like this one is a yes), or all of the above. Once you define all of those questions, then you can see if something like DNS round robin would work, or if you need something like Torque to setup a batch scheduler, or if all you need is a MySQL cluster, etc

Comment: My software need to receive requisitions of all the computers, for distribute between the computers that have "the hardware" that I named it "SAT". I editted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`lvs`, `openais` are both open source. The problem is to use clusters and/or load-balancers properly. That includes deep technical knowledge about what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you by the answer.  I'will read about these themes that you said.